# Proper way to iterate through a list which may not be a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iteration

Currently i am getting information from an xml file. 
If an xml tag has more then one children it will return as a list inside that tag, however if that xml tag has only 1 child it will return not as a list and only as a regular string.

My question is: is there a better way to iterate through this tag? if it is a list, iterate through the list length amount of times, but if it is a string only iterate once?

This is my current approach:

```
 #check if tag is a list, if not then make a list with empty slot at end
 if not isinstance(accents['ac'], list):
      accents['ac'] = list((accents['ac'], {}))

 #loop through guaranteed list
 for ac in accents['ac']: #this line throws error if not list object!

      #if the empty slot added is encountered at end, break out of loop
      if bool(ac) == False:
            break
```

any ideas on how to make this cleaner or more professional is appreciated.

Comment: What's the xml library you're using? Maybe it has a builtin way of doing that.

Comment: Why are you adding empty dict at the end and then checking for it? Why cannot you just create a list of single element?

Comment: the reason for adding a slot in the end is because if i don't and i try to loop through a single slot list, it will loop through every character in the string instead of just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the problem is caused by `accents['ac']` being either a list of string or a single string, a simple processing could be:

```
 #check if tag is a list, if not then make a list with empty slot at end
 if not isinstance(accents['ac'], list):
      accents['ac'] = [ accents['ac'] ]

 #loop through guaranteed list
 for ac in accents['ac']: #this line throws error if not list object!
     ...
```

Comment: correct! this was the proper answer, i guess i was using `list()` wrong

Answer (score 0):

For readabilities sake, it might be better to do

```
if isinstance(accents['ac'], str):
    pass #insert what you want to happen here when it is a string
else:
    for(ac in accents['ac']):
        pass #insert what you want to happen here when it is a list
```

Answer (score 0):

suppposing that i want to add them to a list, i would check if its a nested tag first then add them.

```
 tag_list=[]    
 if(len(accents['ac'])>1):
   for tag in accents['ac']:
       tag_list.append(tag)
 else:
   tag_list.append(tag)
```